# Shellshock Vulnerability Information on Information Security Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Over on the [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/), we have created a Community Wiki question to address some of the concerns regarding Shellshock vulnerabilities.

[What operating systems and devices are known to be affected by Shellshock? What patches are available?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68368/what-operating-systems-and-devices-are-known-to-be-affected-by-shellshock-what)

This is simply a list of products which have been confirmed to be vulnerable to Shellshock, and their patch availability status with regards to the multiple Shellshock-related vulnerabilities. While this cannot, by nature, be considered a comprehensive or authoritative list, it is hoped that it will help to answer the common questions of "Am I affected?" and "How do I patch?".

I would like to encourage everyone to point users to the above question, if the information they seek is already provided in the CW answer. If you have information that can be added to the answer, please edit it in. Given the breadth and severity of the Shellshock vulnerabilities, having all of this information consolidated on one page could provide a great resource for Internet users seeking to understand and address the problem, and it could also be a great driver of traffic for the Information Security Stack Exchange site and Stack Exchange in general.

Additionally, other questions with some relevant information may be found under the [Shellshock tag](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shellshock) on the Information Security StackExchange.

Comment: But why post this here? What's this got to do with SE, other than the post being on one of our sites? If this is purely promotional, it really doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Oded Many (if not most) of the SE sites are IT-centric, and are certain to be getting (if not already have gotten) a large influx of questions regarding Shellshock in the near future. I figured here was the appropriate place to get the word out to everyone who would be interested and affected, instead of posting a ton of questions across various site-specific Metas. Generally, a question like the one linked above is not SE-appropriate either, but the Sec.SE mods allowed it in the overriding interest of "making the Internet a better place".

Comment: Sorry, but all that reads to me as a solution looking for a problem. We have not had a large influx of questions regarding Shellshock. Good to have a place where so much information exists but MSE is not the place to promote it.

Comment: The truth is that a post on MSE is a drop in the bucket compared to the traffic Google sends our way on this vulnerability. So posting here isn't really solving a problem. We don't have a good way of consolidating similar questions that turn up across many sites and I don't think posting on MSE will really help. It's probably better to let Google's algorithms figure this out.

Comment: @Oded I'm most active on Sec.SE and SU. I've seen plenty of Shellshock questions on Sec.SE, and also a few on SU. As of now, there's over 50 on Sec.SE, 10 on SU, and over 30 on SO. As this is a situation, and a solution, that is obviously going to affect several StackExchange communities, I don't see any more appropriate place to discuss it.

Comment: @JonEricson This MSE topic isn't intended to be a canonical or easily-searchable reference for everyone to see when they're looking for Shellshock info. Active MSE users are generally a relatively small subset of StackExchange users in general, anyway. However, that subset is also generally the group that cares the most about making SE and the Internet a better place. It only seems logical to inform them that there is a canonical CW question on an SE site, and to invite them to participate in building upon it, for a topic that's certain to see a lot of attention across many SE sites.

Comment: @Iszi See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146893/are-macs-vulnerable-to-the-bash-shellshock-bug? and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146849/how-do-i-recompile-bash-to-avoid-shellshock-the-remote-exploit which aren't covered on your SE topic yet.

Comment: @Iszi: I appreciate effort, but I just think it's misplaced. There are a lot of questions across the network about Shellshock because it's a hot topic. When I first learned of it, I immediately searched Google to see if ksh was vulnerable and learn the details. [A question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157329/what-does-env-x-command-bash-do-and-why-is-it-insecure) on [Unix.SE] was in my results and my questions were answered there. The question you pointed to on [Security.SE] does not answer my questions and that's ok. There doesn't need to be a single canonical question and answer.

Comment: @Troyen Thanks. There's a lot of other products I'm aware are or may be vulnerable that I've been meaning to dig up and post web references for, and OS X was definitely high on the list. However, it would also help if others would contribute. If only one person is contributing, updates are limited to that person's availability, knowledge, and diligence. And if people don't contribute, there's really little point in having it as a CW at all.